# JqGrid not loading data from JSON format from PHP

Tags: json, jqgrid

Can Some one help me and point me where i am going wrong. Appreciate your help. The Grid shows Blank and nothing is getting loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.1.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url:'http://localhost/jqgrid/book.php',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Title', 'Author', 'Publisher'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'title' , width:160},
        {name:'author' ,width:180},
        {name:'publisher' ,width:80}
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'title',
    sortorder: "desc",
    height: 'auto',
    width: 900,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption:"JSON Example",
    jsonReader : {
        repeatitems: true,
        cell: "cell",
        id:"id",
        userdata: "userdata",
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records"
       }  
});

jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:true,del:true});

});

</script>

</head>

<body>

     <table id="list2"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
     <div id="pager2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here my JSON Response from PHP:

{"page":"1","total":1,"records":"2","rows":[{"id":"2","cell":["PHP QUERY","JSON","VTECH"]},{"id":"1","cell":["JQUERY Cook book","MY AUTHOR","GRID"]}]}

Answer (score 0):

The code which you posted is in general correct. You can see that on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user1831178.htm).

The reason of the problem could be for example the usage of **absolute URL path** `url:'http://localhost/jqgrid/book.php'` instead of *relative* like `url:'book.php'` or `url:'/jqgrid/book.php'`. Another possible reason could be wrong `Content-Type` value in the HTTP header of the JSON response. I recommend you never use absolute URL in Ajax requests because you are able to use URL only from *the same web server* because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). So it's better to use always *relative* URL.